# automatically add a new models to admin page

Tags: python, django

i have a calculator app, inside it i have a Transaction , Family_group , Family_member models see pic below.
[image]

i want everytime i try to make a new Transaction there will be a default 1 Family_group and Family_member added automatically, without me starting one each time. is there any way to do it ?
models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
   income_period_choices = (('Weekly', 'Weekly'), ('Fortnightly',
                                                'Fortnightly'))
   chp_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   rent_effective_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   income_period = models.CharField(max_length=11,
                                 choices=income_period_choices,
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True, default='Weekly')
   property_market_rent = models.DecimalField(help_text='Weekly',
                                           max_digits=7,
                                           decimal_places=2,
                                           null=True,
                                           blank=True)
class FamilyGroup(models.Model):
   name_choices = (('FG_1', 'FG_1'), ('FG_2',
                                   'FG_2'), ('FG_3', 'FG_3'), ('FG_4', 
                  'FG_4'), ('FG_5', 'FG_5'))
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=name_choices)
  transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   family_type = models.ForeignKey(FamilySituation,
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                null=True,
                                blank=True)
class FamilyMember(models.Model):
   transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   family_group = models.ForeignKey(FamilyGroup,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
   date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   relationship = models.ForeignKey(Relationship, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to help, but this might get you started:

You can override the `save` method on the `Transaction` model like so:

```py
class Transaction(models.Model):

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # add / create family group if it is missing:
        if not self.family_group:
            self.family_group = <the Family_group instance>

            # add / create family member if it is missing:
            if not self.family_group.family_member_set.all()
                self.family_group.add([<the Family_member instance>])
                self.family_group.save()

        return super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i added the models.py please look, how can i use self.family_group in Transaction model ?

Comment: Can just push that guy into the first if statement - see edit. You'll need to add your own logic for when a `Family_group` or `Family_member` should be added, created, looked up, etc.

Comment: its giving me syntax error at first if statement. family_group is what? there is a FamilyGroup model .